# How do I count occurance of bab in arbabababtybab using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Please note that second bab starts where first one ends. This is why using `in` command isn't giving accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `regex`. I think what you want is a *`positive lookahead`*. This basically means that you can search for overlapping occurrences of a pattern (`bab`).

So, I created a [**`regex101`**](https://regex101.com/r/YZH5hv/2) for the expression that will work for this.

And implemented in Python:

```
import re
s = 'arbabababtybab'
o = re.findall('(?=(bab))', s)
n = len(o)
```

which gives `o` (the occurrences) as a `list` of: `['bab', 'bab', 'bab', 'bab']` and `n` as the number of them (the *count*): `4`.

---

Alternatively, you could use string `slicing` to do this with a `list-comprehension`:

```
s = 'arbabababtybab'
o = [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)-2) if s[i:i+3] == 'bab']
n = len(o)
```

which gives the *same* results as above.

Comment: `sum(1 for i in range(len(s)-2) if s[i:].startswith('bab')]`